# Remote url environment variable

Tags: git, git-remote

I want to add a submodule with a variable in the path so that everyone can use the same .gitmodules.

ie... `git submodule add $USER/pub/repo.git` I don't want $USER to expand inside .gitmodules. I tried `git submodule add '$USER/pub/repo.git'` but it cannot find the repo. I see the same behavior when trying to add a remote with an env variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's impossible because `git` doesn't expand environment variables in URLs.

To do what you want use [`git config --global url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) to substitute URLs on the fly. Everyone in your team has to set URL replacement:

```
git config --global url.<new-url>.insteadOf <old-url>
```

See more examples in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+insteadof

Comment: In my specific example.. `git config --global url.$USER/pub GITPUB` Then in repo. `git submodule add GITPUB/repo.git` 
PS. Your knowledge is impressive